# First occurring non-repeating number

Tags: c++

Assume you have a vector of numbers for example:
0,4,2,3,1,0,6,4

Find the first number in this list that is not repeated. So for the examples sake the answer is 2. 
Assumptions:

- You can modify the vector provided
- If you cant find anything return -1
- Numbers provided are between 0 - 10,000

I have provided two answers that I have thought of, and I think the function called `ArraySolution` is the best, however can anybody think of something that is faster and explain :)

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <map>

void FillVectorRandomly(std::vector<int>& numbers, int size, int lowerRange, int higherRange)
{
        if(size == 0)
                return;
        if(lowerRange < 0)
                return;
        if(higherRange < lowerRange)
        {
                int temp = lowerRange;
                lowerRange = higherRange;
                higherRange = temp;
        }

        srand(time(NULL));
        int dif = higherRange - lowerRange+1;

        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                numbers.push_back((rand() % dif) + lowerRange);
}

int MapSolution(std::vector<int>& numbers)
{
        std::map<int, int> mapNumbers;

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
        {
                mapNumbers[numbers[i]] = mapNumbers[numbers[i]] + 1;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
        {
                if(mapNumbers[numbers[i]] == 1)
                        return numbers[i];
        }
        return -1;
}

int ArraySolution(std::vector<int>& numbers)
{
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
        {

                if(numbers[i] != -1)
                {
                        int count = 0;
                        for(int j = i+1; j < numbers.size(); ++j)
                        {
                                if(numbers[j] == numbers[i])
                                {
                                        numbers[j] = -1;
                                        count++;
                                }
                        }
                        if(count == 0)
                                return numbers[i];
                }
                numbers[i] = -1;
        }
}
int main()
{
        std::vector<int> numbers;
        FillVectorRandomly(numbers, 4, 0, 5);
        int m = MapSolution(numbers);
        int a = ArraySolution(numbers);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not `std::stable_sort` and then go through elements sequentially till you find non-repeating number.

Comment: "first number" - is that before sorting, or after? From your example it could be either. What would the correct answer be if the input was `[3 4 0 5 3 5]`? Is it `0`, or `4`?

Comment: @Naveen You sort the numbers and then they no longer have their orignal order! Do the sort on the example and the answer is 1 which is wrong :)

Comment: @Floris 4 would be the answer

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review and thus belongs in [codereview.se]

Comment: @Rapptz: not so... question doesn't ask for review, it says "can anybody think of something that is faster and explain?"

Comment: @TonyD Those questions are typically found in codereview as well, e.g. "Can someone tell me how to improve this code to be faster?". Same thing, just phrased differently.

Comment: @Rapptz: no it's not - "think of something faster" is different from "think how to make *this* faster".  Mark's solution shows that a totally different algorithm is possible and better.

Comment: @TonyD ummm... maybe not Mark's but I think this was novel enough to maybe warrent taking off hold

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: true... Mark's answer didn't pan out - but clearly the focus of answers has been on alternative algos rather than reviewing those in the question.

Comment: @TonyD yes, I agree on the focus being alt answers, I'm not sure a question has to give broken code, he demonstrated he knew the space and demonstrated it with code, so if I could, I'd vote unblock

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MapSolution` is O(N log(N)) since there are N inserts O(logN) -- also Size is O(NlogN)

`ArraySolution` seems to be O(N^2) since there are N loopsof some fraction of N - but K might be good

The following is O(N) with size O(1) since the lookup is fixed:

```
int lookup_solution(std::vector<int>& numbers)
{
        int lookup[10000+1] = {};
        for (int i=0; i<numbers.size(); ++i)
        {
                lookup[numbers[i]]++;
        }
        for (int i=0; i<numbers.size(); ++i)
        {
                if (lookup[numbers[i]] == 1)
                {
                        return numbers[i];
                }
        }

        return -1;
}
```

It takes advantage of the fact that the input range is only 10000 and so there are N inserts that are O(1) :

•Numbers provided are between 0 - 10,000

**EDIT:** As noted in comments *(my version)*, for a large input vector:

```
int lookup_solution(std::vector<int>& numbers)
{
        static const int max_value=10000;
        int count[max_value+1] = {};  // counts occurrences of index 
        int order[max_value+1];       // keeps order of values seen 
        int index[max_value+1];       // index into order for where order is found
        int order_index=0;

        for (int i=0; i<numbers.size(); ++i)
        {
                int n=numbers[i];
                int seen=count[n];
                if (seen == 0)             // first time
                {                        
                    count[n]=1;
                    order[order_index]=n;
                    index[n]=order_index;
                    order_index++;
                }
                else if (seen == 1)      // not eligible (-1)
                {                       
                    count[n]=-1;         // use -1 since it might be in a register
                    order[index[n]]=-1; 
                } // else do nothing
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < order_index; ++i)
        {
             if (order[i] != -1)
             {
                   return order[i];
             }
        }   
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence, but try with input `[1, 2, 1, 2, 3]`. P.S. I've made an edit.

Comment: @MarkRansom - removed reference to your solution - ya thanks for catching my flawed testing - should have used mine as an oracle

Comment: If `numbers.size()` is vastly more than 10,000, and the first non-repeating value a long way into `numbers`, you might get usefully faster performance maintaining a `size_t first_seen_at[10001]` index and searching it with `std::min_element`.  (`if (++lookup[numbers[i]] == 1) first_seen_at[numbers[i]] = i;` / `&*std::min_element(first_seen_at, first_seen_at + 10001) - first_seen_at`).

Comment: Sorry - not quite as simple as I wrote above and probably can't use std::min_element as you'd need to crossreference with `lookup[]` to see which numbers to consider when finding the minimum/earliest position in numbers.  Still, that second loop is over 10001 elements instead of up to O(N) (and *always* O(N) when there are no seen-once values).

Comment: @TonyD a simple solution if there are vastly more than 10,000, is to simply check before finding the solution (the second loop) check to see if there is a solution, which with that many numbers is unlikely - that will roughly halve the time.   Any other tracking will likely increase the time for the first loop beyond the time of the second and net cost more than it saves

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: that would help for the no-solution case - what's left is cases where the first unrepeated value is way, way past position 10k which is probably borderline pathological ;-).  For the sake of discssion, in that case I'd doubt "Any other tracking will likely ... net cost more than it saves" - when scanning a really large vector, the stalls for main memory reads are likely to be the dominant factor, leaving any `if (++x == 1)` (which will be entered at most 10k times and therefore branch prediction will work nicely) filling a little otherwise-idle time....

Comment: Have written and benchmarked it... in a pathologically unlikely worst case, the approach I describe runs in 2091ms (all passes) vs 2948ms for the solution in your answer (with O(N) second pass) on my PC for 100 billion element vector.  As I said, the issue here is memory caching performance, not a few extra instructions in the first loop.  I'm not saying it's not overkill - just mentioned it originally as an alternative for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @TonyD - posted my version of reducing the second loop.  If yours is faster, can you post it someplace.  Either way I'd like to see the benchmark of my second version :)  Also, any idea at roughly what size the large version becomes faster - then you can simply choose based on size.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Thank you, very much. This is an approach I just didnt think of due to using that much potentially unused array worries me!

Comment: @ChrisCondy, the first version presented here could use less memory if the single `lookup` array were replaced with two `bitset` or `vector<bool>`, `seen` and `repeated`. You really don't care how many times a value is repeated, just whether it is or not. Don't know how that would affect run time.

Comment: @MarkRansom I understand the logic of whats happening and such. What I was trying to say is I would of never thought of this solution or would of discarded it as bad for wasting(potentially) so much space. And hence I like the solution because it gives me an answer that I naturally would of not thought of! As I was looking for a solution that would improve my problem solving skills.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: code at http://ideone.com/A9ccEc - timing's for Windoze and may need porting.  I was stupid and ran it unoptimised yesterday - getting ~281ms vs ~375 at -O2 with MS compiler v15.  I haven't benchmarked your new version - will have a look in a sec.  Cheers.

Comment: @ChrisCondy: when people start measuring algorithm performance using big-O notation, it's only meaningful for huge numbers of inputs, so taking a bit of an up-front fixed-size hit in memory usage is a common sacrifice.  The fact that the question bothers to state that the numbers are in a specific range implies that's significant, and the questioner is actively fishing for such an approach.  For real use, you might even have an initial branch between alternative implementations based on the input size.